Why am I encountering a stack frame access violation despite staying within stack and heap limits?

I'm working on a program in Solana and running into a strange issue where I'm encountering a stack frame access violation, even though the context size of my instructions seems well within the stack and heap limits.
Here’s the setup and the issue:
Case 1: Using a normal Account (no zero copy, no box)
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>, 

    #[account(init, space = 8 + CounterData::INIT_SPACE, payer = payer)]
    pub counter: Account<'info, CounterData>, 

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>, 
}

// Context size: 1673 bytes
// CU: 6389
#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct CounterData {
    test: u8, 
    pubkey_array: [Pubkey; 49], 
}

When using Account<'info, CounterData> directly, the instruction context size is 1673 bytes, which should be within the stack limit (4KB). However, when initializing the account, I encounter the following error:

failed: Access violation in stack frame 9 at address 0x200009ff0 of size 8

This error is confusing because the context size (1673 bytes) is well below the stack limit of 4KB.
Case 2: Using Box<Account>
To avoid loading the full account on the stack, I switched to using Box<Account<'info, CounterData>>, which should allocate the data on the heap instead.
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>, 

    #[account(init, space = 8 + CounterData::INIT_SPACE, payer = payer)]
    pub counter: Box<Account<'info, CounterData>>, 

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>, 
}

// Context size: 1993 bytes
// CU: 6389
#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct CounterData {
    test: u8, 
    pubkey_array: [Pubkey; 62], 
}

Here, the instruction context size increases slightly to 1993 bytes, but this is still below the 4KB stack limit. Additionally, using Box should allow up to 32KB of heap allocation for the account data. Yet, I encounter the same error:

failed: Access violation in stack frame 9 at address 0x200009ff0 of size 8

My Setup
I’m using the solana-test-validator with the following command:
solana-test-validator -r --deactivate-feature EenyoWx9UMXYKpR8mW5Jmfmy2fRjzUtM7NduYMY8bx33

The deactivated feature ensures that the stack and heap limits are as expected (4KB for the stack, 32KB for the heap).
Questions

Why am I encountering this access violation error when both the context size and heap allocation are well within their respective limits?
Is there something I’m misunderstanding about how Solana handles stack frames or heap allocation in this case?
Could this be a bug in the solana-test-validator, or am I missing some critical detail in my implementation?

Any insights into why this issue is happening or how to debug it further would be greatly appreciated!

